# Eclipse Java syntax error on token "enum",identifier expected

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, enums

I'm trying to compile my source code. However, I'm keep getting the following error:

**Syntax error on token  "enum", Identifier expected**

The fact of the matter is java compiler is set to 1.6 in eclipse now and I know that enum keyword is depricated after java 5. Even though I decrease my java compiler to 1.5 and clean project/rebuild. Error is still not fixed. Here you can see the error.

[As you can see on top of the page package statement with red line under it causes an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRUq3.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code as text. Don't link to code on another site, and don't use pictures of text.

Comment: That's a typo. Use org.apache.commons.lang.enums.Enum or org.apache.commons.lang.enums.*

Comment: Both -source and -target are set to 1.5?

Answer (score 3):

`enum` is a keyword since Java 5 and therefore not allowed as a segment in a package name:

In ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler*** set the ***Compiler compliance level*** to **1.4**.

Furthermore, **`src/org/apache/commons/lang/enum`** should not be a source folder: **right-click** the folder and choose ***Build Path > Remove from Build Path***.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, I already tried what you said but it still does not clear the errors,which is pretty weird.

Comment: @theroglu At least this `Syntax error on token "enum", Identifier expected` error should be fixed. Which remaining errors do you have?

Comment: Actually it didn't change anything that's why im confused.Normally as you said it , syntax errors should be cleared but still I get

Syntax error on token "enum", Identifier expected  error and also 
The declared package "" does not match  the expected package "org.apache.commons.lang.enum"

Comment: See my edited answer: _"Furthermore, ..."_. If the errors persist, try _Project > Clean..._.

Answer (score -2):

Try deleting and create/reimport your project (OR) set your JRE workspace to 1.5 ,then apply and save it.Also, try rebuilding your project.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I already tried what you said multiple times, seems to not work, sadly.